# From what wavelength can radiation go through a human body without very much changing?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Gamma-rays can go through a body but they will ionize a lot of atoms (I don't know whether some of the gamma photons will go through without any interaction at all?). The same for X-rays. Visible light and infrared (till $1mm$) probably only reflects and absorbs. But perhaps rays from 1 cm and longer (radiowaves) can get through the human body without harming the body or without changing in frequency?

Comment: Penetration depth *decreases* with increasing frequency. [Here](http://etheses.whiterose.ac.uk/4676/7/gmthesis2_3.pdf) is a PhD thesis on the subject.

Comment: Your microwave oven has a frequency of approx. 2.4GHz and a wavelength of approx. 12cm and that wavelength will definitely get absorbed by your body really well. There are national and international em radiation limits at basically all frequencies almost all the way to DC and with good reason. The human body does absorb and will be affected at essentially all frequencies.

Comment: here is the link you're looking for
http://www.pemft.net/physics-of-pemf---radiation--light.html

Answer (score 3):

There are two effects of electromagnetic  waves on human body.

1. Heating effects, occurring mostly around 2.45 GHz (which is the frequency used in microwave ovens)
2. Ionizing effects, which can damage human body and cells

Here is a picture of how the radiowaves penetrate the human body according to the frequency.
The legend is from 1 to 10 : Cosmic rays, gamma rays, X-rays, ultraviolet, visible spectrum, infrared, microwaves, radiowaves, very low frequencies, extremely low frequencies.

[image]

Comment: How do I have to interpret the arrows?

Comment: It gives the approximate length of how much the radiowave penetrates the human body at this frequency. e.g. all waves below 100 Mhz get through while light and infrared do not (of course)

Comment: you do not give a link of the source for the plot

Comment: The penetration should be in cm per wavelength (modified by power), but this chart seems to be pretty much off the hip accurate.
(edit) The chart is referenced at the top with a link to a thesis done
“Electromagnetic Absorption by the Human Body from 1 to 15 GHz Gregory Connor Richard Melia A thesis submitted for the Ph.D. degree The University of York Department of Electronics”
The thesis also points out different parts of the body - skin, fat, muscle bone blood, fluids all filter out (absorb ) or let pass through different wavelengths at different amounts. So with a single chart, the best

Comment: [ctd from prev comment]: you can hope for is a fuzzy abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

There's no uniform relationship between wavelength and extent of penetration/absorption. It's a quite complex function of both wavelength and material.

There are examples of low as well as high frequencies which penetrate, as well as some middle ones that don't. Also, from among the penetrating ones, some are also absorbed, some not.

Regarding health, general scientific consensus is that penetrating ones harm only if they are ionizing or heat the body to the extreme.

The image in MaximGi's answer seems fine, here are 2 more references I could find:

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/a-Tissue-penetration-depth-of-light-with-different-wavelengths-NIR-light-penetrates_fig13_316712743
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Evaluation-of-absorbed-light-dose-in-human-skin-by-Chang-Huang/fc946510ccb0b616fa66ab7d7324197564492533

Answer (score 0):

I assume "...modified by power..." in one of the comments was referring to a wave's amplitude. It is a simple but hugely important factor to remember for considering the energy level, and by extension, the level of potential harm to the human body. A microwave oven (high amplitude -> high energy) at its frequency of 2.45Ghz will cook food, while a router emitting at the same or higher frequency (2.4Ghz to 5Ghz) won't. Associated with that is the distance from the emitter where the inverse square of the amplitude determines the degree of effect (e.g. two times the distance is one quarter the effect).

References:
https://www.sciencelearn.org.nz/resources/2681-waves-and-energy-energy-transfer
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave